# What is the meaning of 製年德宣明大,,please tell me?

Tags: translation, meaning, character-identification, phrase, dictionary

[image: Images or writing that I photographed from Gucci/Vas]製年德宣明大
I got this post from Gucci/Vas. Is this a sentence or a code? Does this article have any meaningful meaning?

Comment: So does the writing/code have a special meaning and use? Does the code identify the item?

Comment: 大明宣德年製 means "Made during the XuanDe period (1426—1435) of the Ming dynasty "There is no special meaning. Just like "2024, Made In China" has no special meaning besides identifying when and where something was made

Comment: So, are items/objects that have this writing considered antiques? Does this item have value if sold?

Comment: If the writing on the item was true that it is 600 years old, then it could be worth thousands of dollars. However,  anyone could write these words at any time. To know the value, console a reputable antique dealer, If it is a replica, it is still worth $20 - $100, depending on the quality and the market. Also, please don't post comments as answers, click on the "Add a comment" link to post a comment or click "Edit" to add additional questions to your post

Answer (score 3):

You should be reading right to left here and it becomes
大明宣德年製 which means "made in the year of 大明宣德"

The “宣德” XuanDe period during the “明” Ming dynasty was between 1426—1435

Answer (score 0):

大明(dà Míng) The Great Ming Dynasty
宣德(Xuāndé) it used to be the title of emperor during the the period (1426-1435)
年製 (niánzhì) manufacturing year

So, if you combine, it becomes “made during Xuande of Ming dynasty”